# Describing the coefficients of the 91-th root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_3)$. Consider the basis $\mathcal{B} = (1,\zeta_3)$ of $K$ as a $\mathbb{Q}_5$-space.

Also, let $\zeta_{91}$ be a primitive 91th-root of unity in $\bar{K}$.

> **Question** How can I describe the coeffients of $\min_K(\zeta_{91})$ in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}$ 
>  (i.e. in the form $c_i = a_i+b_i \zeta_3$ where $c_i$ are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial and $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Q}_5$)?

**Progress**:

- I know that $K(\zeta_{91})/K$ is unramified and has degree $6$, so the minimal polynomial has degree $6$.
- The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{91}$ over $K$ is (if I recall correctly) $\prod_{j=0}^5 (x-\zeta_{91}^{25^j})$. I thought it might be helpful to look at how this would work over $\mathbb{C}$, so I tried to compute the result in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%29*%28%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%5E25%29%29*%28%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%5E79%29%29*%28%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%5E64%29%29*%28%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%5E53%29%29*%28%28x-exp%282*pi*i%2F91%29%5E51%29%29). However, it did not look very useful to me. I only thought that this result from it might help me:

[image]

Is there a better approach to deal with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if one can give "exact" formulae for the coefficients, but an alternative way of producing successive $5$-adic approximation would be to use Hensel lifting.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: Could you please elaborate? Do you mean computing the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{91}$ over its residue field first?

Comment: Well its constant coefficient is $1$ ... otherwise that WA printout just repeats what one should know via symmetric polynomials, but of course the complex normalisation with $2\pi$ is not helpful here. E.g. the coefficent of $x^5$ in our context is better expressed as $-(\zeta+\zeta^{25}+ \zeta^{79}+\zeta^{64}+\zeta^{53}+\zeta^{51})$, where $\zeta=\zeta_{91}$, but how to write that in the basis $\mathcal B$ ...

Comment: Not sure of it actually helps, but if one is stuck otherwise, certainly finding the minimal polynomial over the residue field does no harm ...